# How to link to a specific answer?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

How can I link to a specific answer on a question, such that when the link is followed it scrolls down to the answer?  I have seen this done and know how to do it for comments (simply click on the date posted) but have not figured out how for an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look under the answer and press the *Share* button, it will give you a link with your unique userid attached at the end (for several reasons such as when you share links, the views can be attributed back to you for badges etc).