# Helpful post reference index

Tags: discussion, search

This is a place to keep track of and categorize good questions or answers which may be helpful to refer to at a later time, a kind of general Blender reference index.  If you find a post which you think belongs here feel free to add it to the corresponding answer.

Please keep a few things in mind when adding to the list:

- **This is for keeping track of general descriptions of basic Blender tasks or common questions/answers that arise**, which would be useful to point other users towards in the future.
- Please follow the organization already set up.  Each **category** (not link) has it's own answer.  To add a reference just edit the proper answer and add the link.  If you feel you need to create a new category please ask about it first and get approval.
- If you do add a new category please also edit this post to add it to the contents section below (in alphabetical order).
- This is not a place to put links to your posts just to get rep.  That said, if you honestly feel that a post of yours meets the standards feel free to add it.
- Use the <kbd>share</kbd> button under an answer to link to a specific answer, see [this meta post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/580/how-to-link-to-a-specific-answer).

---

#### Contents:

[Blender Internal (render engine)](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/870/5705)
[Cycles](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/869/5705)
[Modeling](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/868/5705)
[Python Scripting](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/871/5705)

---

*Note: this was [discussed in meta here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/site-index-proposal-for-useful-reference-questions-answers), if you have any comments or questions about this post please add them to the original meta proposal.*

Comment: related: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/frequenty-asked-questions-on-blender-stack-exchange

Answer (score 5):

### Modeling

---

#### Explanations and technical stuff:

- [Applying transforms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation)
- [Texture coordinates description](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23173/what-methods-can-be-used-to-place-a-texture-onto-an-object/23174#23174)
- [Explanation of normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21190/what-are-face-normals)

#### Common problems:

- [Inside faces caused by mirror](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/52181/5705)

#### Tips:

- [Quickly creating a city](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/how-can-i-quickly-generate-create-a-large-city-without-modeling-it-all-by-hand)
- [Creating a spiral "onion dome"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/how-would-i-go-about-creating-a-spiralled-dome/2318#2318)

Answer (score 5):

### Cycles

---

#### Explanations and technical stuff:

- [Differences from BI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)
- [Explanation of ray tracing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34229/5705)
- [Explanation of BVH](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32473/5705)
- [BVH settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7510/why-is-rendered-viewport-faster-than-rendering-individual-frames/7524#7524)
- [Branched path tracing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful)
- [BSDF description](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/786/5705)

#### Tips and tricks:

- [Finding edges/corners of a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3370/is-it-possible-to-generate-an-image-based-on-edges-and-corners)
- [Speeding up rendering interior scenes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33145/blender-cycles-slow-rendering-interior-scene)
- [Avoiding aliased edges around emission shaders](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17844/aliased-edge-around-light-source-in-cycles)
- [Bluring a texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/how-to-blur-a-texture-node-in-cycles-material)
- [Enabling GPU rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7485/599)

#### Useful shaders:

- [Sci-fi force field shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15742/5705)
- [Old painted cement shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35224/how-can-i-make-a-realistic-cement-shader-with-old-cracks-crumbling-paint-chippin)
- [Mirror shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23913/how-to-create-a-mirror-shader)
- [Snow shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18603/how-to-make-a-realistic-snow-material-in-cycles)
- ["Moon rock" shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32133/5705)
- [Sugar cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35542/5705)

Answer (score 3):

### Blender internal (render engine)

---

- [Differences from Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

Answer (score 2):

### Python scripting

---

#### Tips:

#### Helpful code snippets: